# Customized Custom Url Scheme not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

I am developing iPhone app . Which is like e-commerce app. In that i want to handle custom url.

My url is something like this : ***www.abc.com/m/view.html?productId=123&name=user*** .

Now I want to handle this custom url. I have added custom url scheme as shown in screenshot. It works on iOS 8 . For iOS 9 and later it not working. I have also whitelisted scheme name .

In iOS 9 and later when I try to open url in safari , I can see pop up like **"Want's to open app ?"** with cancel and open button . but after some time it dismissed automatically .

Can you please help me to solve this ?

Thanks in advance ..!!!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your deepLink should look like

```
abc://www.abc.com/m/view.html?productId=123&name=user
```

because you did register **URL Schemes** as a **abs** not a **http** or others

Comment: if i register url schemes as . http:// www.example.com? should it works ?

Comment: No **http** URL Scheme is reserved.

Comment: do i have to change url while generating app link ?

Comment: If you have a server. It can handle standard link like http:// www.example.com and redirect to your link like abc://www.abc.com/m/view.html?productId=123&name=user

Comment: Yes . i have server but if my app is not installed then it should be open in safari . Does this works ?

Comment: Your server should solve this case. When you send request to your server with standard path it should check using javascript and timeout did install your app or not by change path to deeplink.

Comment: is there any other ways . if i register different URL Schemes ?

Comment: I think no. different URL Schemes nothing will change

Comment: Only way i can do is . to perform change on backend side . ?

Comment: i have added javascript on my server side and it works for me when i am using chrome mobile browser . but it not working when i try to open link in safari .